# Why does my machine code not behave as expected?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, machine-code, dosbox

I am using the DOSBox debugger as an environment to explore how an x86/64 based processor traverses machine code.

As a reference i am using the "DOS2 length-delimited output" example i found at:
https://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Information/LowLevel/Assembly/hello-asm.html

I have tried several different approaches but this is what has produced the results closest to what i am looking for.

I am using a hex editor to enter the bytes manually and here is the hex-code i currently have saved in a file called "executable.com":

```
68 DD 01 1F B2 00 B6 00 B1 06 B3 01 B4 40 B0 00
CD 21 B4 4C B0 00 CD 21 48 65 6C 6C 6F 21 0A D0
0A 24 20
```

Executing this file through the debugger gives the following code overview:

```
01DD:0100  68DD01              push 01DD
01DD:0103  1F                  pop  ds
01DD:0104  B200                mov  dl,00
01DD:0106  B600                mov  dh,00
01DD:0108  B106                mov  cl,06
01DD:010A  B301                mov  bl,01
01DD:010C  B440                mov  ah,40
01DD:010E  B000                mov  al,00
01DD:0110  CD21                int  21
01DD:0112  B44C                mov  ah,4C
01DD:0114  B000                mov  al,00
01DD:0116  CD21                int  21
```

This is somewhat similar to the code in the link (which i have also tried of course) and it does print a string of length 6 as expected.
However, the string is not fetched from where i want and so the output is just a mess of characters as opposed to the "Hello!" that is present in the hex-code.

Any thoughts on what is going on?

Comment: You are putting `0x1dd` into ds, and 0 into dx.  So ds:dx is 1dd:0.  Have you tried doing a dump of memory at that point?  Something like `d 1dd:0`?

Comment: In addition to loading dx with 0118, the offset of the string, you should load bx with 1, and cx with 6. The code you have doesn’t initialize the upper half of bx and cx.

Comment: You can single-step machine code in a normal 32 or 64-bit process running under your normal OS, using a debugger.  e.g. compile a C "hello world" program and use a debugger like GDB that has an asm / disassembly view.  (Preferably one that will show the hexdump of the machine code along-side.)  Or for example of functions written in x86 machine code, see for example [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) which has links to various answers written in x86 machine code (with corresponding assembly shown).

Comment: Also, here's a fun one: [Determine your language's version](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139717) the same machine-code bytes decode 3 different ways, creating a function that returns 16 in 16-bit mode, 32 in 32-bit mode, and 64 in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes :this is tagged  x86-16. Doesn't help when the target code is using debug.exe and targeting an environment that is either emulated real mode (or virtualized). GDB isn't really an option for debugging 16-bit code. Since he's using debug.exe he can use that to step through his code ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The OP said "to explore how an x86/64 based processor traverses machine code".  I was responding to that, to point out that playing with DOS and 16-bit machine code isn't necessary to accomplish the ultimate goal, and neither is understanding the DOS `int 21h` system-call interface.  (But sure, single-stepping over `int 21h` is maybe easier than stepping over a library function call wrapper around a Windows or Linux system call.)

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I tried doing a dump of the memory, and the memory is seemingly random.
The code you see is the entire program so i actually never load anything into memory.
As i understand(or maybe misunderstand) the example the code segment is repurposed as data storage and the string should be loaded from there.
Does the "msg db 'New hello, World!', 0x0d, 0x0a" create machine code which actually moves data into memory somehow?

Comment: @prl The registers are initialized with all zeros when i start the debugger so the upper halves of bx and cx are already 0.

Comment: @PeterCordes I guess i tried to keep my intentions brief.
My complete goal is to learn more about different kinds of executables such as MZ and PE in order to develop a simple compiler and ultimately learn more about programming language architecture.
The COM-format seemed like a good start as it is basically just pure machine code.

Comment: Yes, I figured that,  but it’s still poor programming practice to rely on it, especially when it’s so easy to simply load the full register.

Comment: @prl It is true that it is bad practice.
I am currently reading from instruction tables to find which opcodes to use and it wasn't worth the distraction as i could clearly see on my end that the register had the correct value loaded.
I realize however that it might cause confusion for a third party reading my code.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense, but toolchains exist to put machine code into the right section of an executable for you, e.g. any assembler would let you write `db 0x68, 0xdd, 0x01, ...` and assemble+link so that ends up as the text or code section of a 32 or 64-bit executable.  I found it easier to learn x86 machine code by writing asm source and looking at the disassembly, though.  There's basically no need to memorize the opcode map or write it by hand to learn about machine code tricks.

Comment: Learning about limitations and corner cases of the ModRM+SIB encoding scheme is fun, though. That explains why 32/64-bit addressing modes have the few limitations:  [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52522544). Of course, 16-bit ModRM encoding is totally different (because 16-bit has no option of coding for a SIB for 2-register modes). Other than that 16-bit machine code is basically the same as other modes, though. Another difference is that VEX prefixes don't work in 16-bit mode, though. (Apparently the illegal encoding they alias was actually used as a trap intentionally.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I have tried to find a way to assemble to a com-file but what i have tried so far has produced a more complex executable.
Do you have any suggestions as to what assembler and or method to use for this purpose?

Comment: `nasm foo.asm` produces a flat binary, aka a `.com` by default.  i.e. `-f bin` is the default output format.  Use `org 0x100` if you want to use symbols for addresses, so NASM knows where the code will be loaded.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks!
I will try that and se if i can find what was wrong with my code and hopefully provide an answer for my own question!

Comment: When your .com file is loaded, then the "Hello!" string is located at `cs:0118`, so I would suggest to load `ds` from `cs` (instead of the hard-coded 01DD, which is bad practice and possibly unreliable) and `dx` with 0118 (instead of 0000, which is obviously wrong).

Comment: @RuudHelderman Yes, i did start of with that but as i didn't get that to work, i changed the value in order to explore the memory.
I unfortunately forgot to change that back before posting my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated the example using NASM as suggested by Peter Cordes which at first produced the exact same results as one of my previous attempts but when i added "org 0x100" to the beginning of my assembly source i got the result i was looking for.

This essentially adds an offset to all addresses which is needed as the code is loaded into memory at address 0x100 as opposed to 0x00.
In this example "org 0x100" only resulted in the change of one bit in the produced result but this one bit was the difference between reading from memory at the correct location and reading 256 bytes to early.

This is how the machine code eventually turned out:

```
BA 13 01 B9 06 00 BB 01 00 B8 00 40 CD 21 B8 00
4C CD 21 48 65 6C 6C 6F 21
```

And the assembly code used to produce it:

```
org 0x100

mov dx, msg
mov cx, 0x06
mov bx, 1
mov ax, 0x4000
int 0x21
mov ax, 0x4C00
int 0x21

msg db "Hello!"
```

Comment: IIRC, `.com` specifies the "tiny" memory model, where all segment registers are equal.  So you don't need to copy CS to DS yourself, and you can count on anything that runs `.com` files loading your program that way.

Comment: This time your code is missing the device handle in `BX` ! (`mov  bx, 1 ; Device handle: STDOUT (screen)`). Also the DOS WriteFile function does not require setting `AL=0` as you wrote.

Comment: @Fifoernik Wow, i must have really absent-minded yesterday.
Well... The code did produce the right result.
I will however update my answer with the correct code in case somebody comes along and copies my mistake!
Thanks for pointing it out!